# Custom Domain with Google App Engine now that Google Apps is not free anymore

Tags: google-app-engine

First I have to apologize if it seems like I am asking a question that has been asked before, but I looked at the Google App Engine documentation and the questions and answers here, and I am finding a lot of inconsistencies.

So my question is: I signed up for a new Google account in August 2013 specifically for developing an app for Google App Engine. I would like to use a custom domain with my app. In the documentation it says that I need to sign up for Google Apps in order to do this. It also says that I can sign up for a free account for 1 person. But it looks like this is not possible anymore since December 2012. I've seen several answers on this here, but they seem outdated as well.

So do I really have to pay $50/year for Google Apps, a service that I really don't need, just to use a custom domain with my Google App Engine App?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually there is one **free** solution, which is not that obvious.

1. Go to AppEngine -> Application Settings -> Add domain -> Sign up for Google Apps
2. Start a free 30 day trial - Do not add the billing options
3. Setup your domain
4. Add the domain to your app engine project
5. When the 30 day trial expire the domain will still **work**.

Comment: I wanted to update my post for a while now because I actually ended up doing exactly that. I signed up for the free trial, set up my domain, and never logged into Google Apps again. It's been a few months since then and it is still working!

Comment: Heh just did it today. So does that means that after `Google App` trial will expire the email will be accessible through `Google App Engine` ?

Comment: No, the domain will only work as google app engine custom domain. To continue using other google app services, you will need to pay the fee.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5967336/use-google-app-engine-to-get-google-apps-for-your-domain-for-free looks like AppEngine should handle single email on custom domain after Google Apps will expire

Comment: It's an old article. That doesn't work anymore... After 30 days, google blocks access to the email. The only thing that will work is the domain as google apps domain. If you want anything else you will need to pay.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM

Comment: Yes... as that discussion thread indicates, currently you can fill out a form to request a credit for your Google Apps account.

Comment: yes, pay $50 first and that $50 can be used for funding your GAE app

Comment: I did see that discussion. The problem is that people posted just a few days ago that they filled out the form and didn't get a response. That's why I sent an email to the address provided but didn't get a response either. So now I'm not sure if they are just slow in responding, or if they don't give that $50 credit anymore...

Comment: I had to wait a week for this response : "Thank you for your recent application for a USD 50 App Engine credit for the application"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I guess I will go ahead and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to pay now. Look in the official appengine issues page, this particular issue has been very active lately. See 
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8528#c24

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a **better free solution**, if you only need one user:

1. Sign up for Google Apps for Business (through Google App Engine)
2. Go to Billing and cancel your whole account.
3. Log in again using the same credentials.

*That's it!* You now have a non-trial, fully functional, good ol' 1 user Google Apps domain.